# Catching STDOUT/STDERR from git

Tags: perl, git, ipc, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to execute a git command from perl via IPC::Run which catches STDOUT/STDERR-Output from git in perl variables.

Here is what i did:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run;
my $stderr, $stdout, @cmd;
push @cmd, "git";
push @cmd, "clone";
push @cmd, "http://my.gitserver.com/scm/tst2/abc.git";

my $success = IPC::Run::run \@cmd, '>', \$stdout, '2>', \$stderr;
1;
```

Running this results in:

- $stdout: *Cloning into 'abc'...*
- $stderr: EMPTY

Running git command from commandline directly results in following output:

```
$ git clone http://my.gitserver.com/scm/tst2/abc.git
Cloning into 'abc'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
```

As you can see, git produces some more output on commandline than I actually capture within my perl implementation.

What's going wrong?

Comment: did you check the $stderr variable? also, when I have to manage a GIT repository from perl, I use the Git::Repository module.

Comment: The extra output might only be provided when STDOUT is connected toa  terminal. If so, providing a pseudo TTY might should convince `git` to output it. Note that it will surely contain many terminal control characters (carriage returns and backspaces).

Comment: @miguel-prz:As I said, `$stderr` is empty after my call ... Using  `Git::Repository` module is not easily usable in my case (as my "server" gets the command to execute from a remote machine and writes the result to a shared sandbox - the received commands can be "anything" - not only git commands ...
@ikegami: Have no idea yet how to do this ...

Comment: What happens when you use Run3 instead of Run? ie: Run3(\@cmd,\$stdin,\$stdout,\$stderr);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is your code is correct. The confusing part is git changes its output depending on whether the standard error is connected to a terminal.

To reproduce your Perl program’s output from a shell, run the following command from a bash prompt.

```
$ git clone http://my.gitserver.com/scm/tst2/abc.git |& cat
Cloning into 'abc'...
```

The `|&` redirection connect the git’s standard error (where the expected progress output goes) and standard output to a pipe rather than the terminal.

To see the usual output, you will have to connect git’s standard error to a [pseudo terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal), also known as a [pty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21147/9941). `IPC::Run` has support for pseudo terminals, described in the [Pseudo Terminals section](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3A%3ARun#PSEUDO_TERMINALS) of its documentation. Instead of redirecting standard error with `2>`, use `2>pty>` instead. Note that this adds a dependency to [`IO::Pty`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3A%3APty).

Tweaking the `run` redirect and adding debug output as in the code below

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Run;

my $cloneurl = 'http://my.gitserver.com/scm/tst2/abc.git';

my($stderr,$stdout);
my @cmd = (qw/ git clone /, $cloneurl);

my $success = IPC::Run::run \@cmd, '>', \$stdout, '2>pty>', \$stderr;
print "success=[$success]\n";
print "stdout=[$stdout]\n";
print "stderr=[$stderr]\n";
```

produces output that resembles

```
success=[1]
stdout=[]
stderr=[Cloning into 'abc'...
remote: Counting objects: 2818, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1965/1965), done.
remote: Total 2818 (delta 1200), reused 770 (delta 287)
Receiving objects: 100% (2818/2818), 2.19 MiB | 1.19 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1200/1200), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
]
```